# Google hack -- inurl:? doesn't work?

Tags: search, search-engine

I want to search some URL within my company's web site, and with at least one "get" parameter.

Something like http://www.mysite.com/info.php?id=212

So, there should be a **?** symbol in it.

However, I tried to use

> **site:.mysite.com filetype:php inurl:?**

And got so many pages without any GET parameter, why does the **inurl:?** not work?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2466433:

> Generally, most punctuation and special characters are ignored in Google Search.

That includes the question mark, and that's why your search doesn't work.